# Prevent access to other directories

Tags: c, webserver

Problem: Implement a webserver, with some basic functionality. However, with this webserver you should not allow any access to a directory above the current directory. This is pretty obvious as nobody should be able to have access above the current directory,otherwise that raises a lot of security issues. My question is how can I put up a check or prevent changing out of the current directory while my program runs. Currently this is how I'm parsing a request that I receive.

With the current implementation a user can change to the directory above the current directory because there is no check. But I can't really figure out an effective way to do so.

```
void handle_request(char * request, int fd)
  {
     /* Request is processed elsewhere, an example of a request is:
      * GET ./a.out 
      * GET /a.out
      * HEAD ./index.html
      * GET /cgi-like/ls?-l&some_file.txt 
      *
      * These are basic requests, that are all in the current directory or
      * the cgi-like sub-directory.
      */
     char * token_request;
     char * token_filename;
     token_request = strtok(request," "); // Determine if GET or HEAD
     token_filename = strtok(NULL," ");

     /* This is where the check should be
      * Check if user is trying to access above the current working dir
      * (e.g GET ../filename) */

     if(strcmp(token_request, "GET") == 0 && check_cgi(token_filename))
     {
       run_cgi(token_filename,fd);
     }
     else if(strcmp(token_request, "GET") == 0)
     {
        run_get(token_filename,fd);
        exit(1);
     }
     else if(strcmp(token_request,"HEAD") == 0)
     {
        run_head(token_filename ,fd);
        exit(1);
     }
     else
     {
        printf("501 Not Implemented\n");
        return;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried... anything? I mean, I can think of one _really_ simple way off the top of my head.

Comment: My solution right not involves just strcat a "./" at the start of the filename. And then checking if a ".." substring exists in the filename. This however, can cause problems if a file such as ..hidden exists.